# count unique value in mysqli colum

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table where i save user views with device name

tbl_views

```
id | profile_id | device
01 | Joe        | Computer
02 | Joe        | Mobile
03 | Mark       | Computer
04 | Joe        | Computer
```

Now i'm showing this on user profile

```
$view=mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tbl_view WHERE profile_id = 'JOE' ");
echo mysqli_num_rows($view);
```

Output is 3

but i want something like this with single query

output : Computer 2, Mobile 0

Now if i want to show how much views user have in specific devices i need to write whole query again and again.. is there anyway to fetch these detail with single query.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you really want but I think you need to modify your SQL statement to something like this:

```
SELECT device, count(device) FROM tbl_views WHERE profile_id = "Joe" GROUP BY device;
```

This will return:

```
device | count(device)

Computer       2
Mobile         1
```

In the statement you are asking we are asking of select all devices (names) and count of this devices that apply to that user (or that the user has used).